# Could not read meta.json

Tags: nlp, spacy

I'm making a resume parser and facing an error.

Parser_1:

```
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
import io
import spacy
import pprint
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
import utils



class ResumeParser(object):

    def __init__(
        self,
        resume,
        skills_file=None,
        custom_regex=None
    ):
        nlp = spacy.load(r"C:\Users\Sauravi\env\Lib\site-packages\en_core_web_sm\en_core_web_sm-3.0.0")
        custom_nlp = spacy.load(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        self.__skills_file = skills_file
        self.__custom_regex = custom_regex
        self.__matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
        self.__details = {
            'name': None,
            'email': None,
            'mobile_number': None,
            'address': None,
            'skills': None,
            'college_name': None,
            'projects': None,
            'designation': None,
            'experience': None,
            'company_names': None,
            'no_of_pages': None,
            'total_experience': None,
        }
        self.__resume = resume
        if not isinstance(self.__resume, io.BytesIO):
            ext = os.path.splitext(self.__resume)[1].split('.')[1]
        else:
            ext = self.__resume.name.split('.')[1]
        self.__text_raw = utils.extract_text(self.__resume, '.' + ext)
        self.__text = ' '.join(self.__text_raw.split())
        self.__nlp = nlp(self.__text)
        self.__custom_nlp = custom_nlp(self.__text_raw)
        self.__noun_chunks = list(self.__nlp.noun_chunks)
        self.__get_basic_details()
```

Error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG6uD.png)

How do I solve this error?
I installed en_core_web_sm using https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0.tar.gz

Comment: Don't post screenshots of errors, just post the error text. You're getting the error at the line loading `custom_nlp` because your parser isn't a spaCy model, like the output of `nlp.to_disk`. You should read the spaCy docs for examples.